# params of the model not being returned rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have made a few posts before this regarding how to add a favourite recipe to a user..I have an app where you can upload recipes once logged in, users can search the entire table for all recipes and view their own recipes  in a member area..

Now I want users to be able to save their favourite recipes, so far I can save a favourite recipe as such, the output that I get is

```
[#<Favourite id: 1, user_id: 8, recipe_id: nil, created_at: "2012-11-06 19:25:34", updated_at: "2012-11-06 19:25:34">,
```

so i am getting the correct user_id but no params for the actual recipe, ie dish name, country of origin.

My models are like so

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :recipes 
has_many :favourites
```

Recipe

```
has_many :ingredients 
has_many :preperations
has_many :favourites
```

Favourite

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :recipe
```

My favourite controller looks like so

```
 def create

 @favourite = current_user.favourites.new(params[:recipe])
 if @favourite.save
 redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Recipe added to Favourites"
 end
end
```

Add to favourites link

```
 <%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create'}, {:method => :post } %>
```

I hope I haven’t missed anything out, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated

```
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  favorite_path(:recipe_id => @recipe.id), {:method => :post } %>
```

BUT this all depends on what  @recipe is defined as in your controller -  for example, if you have

```
@recipes = Recipie.all
```

And in the view you have

```
@recipes.all do |recipe|
```

Then in your link (within the block) you need to have:

```
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  favorite_path(:recipe_id => recipe.id), {:method => :post } %>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add extra information in the link and modify the create action

```
# View
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  favorite_path(:recipe_id => @recipe.id), {:method => :post } %>

# Controller
def create
  @favourite = current_user.favourites.new(recipe_id: params[:recipe_id)
  if @favourite.save
   redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Recipe added to Favourites"
  end
end
```

The problem is you are sending nothing to the controller in the param `params[:recipe]`

**NOTE**: remember the `attr_accessible :user_id, :recipe_id` inside `Favorite` model.

Comment: thanks for answer, have tried your approach also, getting error message Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending any parameters through in the link.

```
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create'}, {:method => :post } %>
```

This isn't enough to add a recipe to the favourites. What you'll need to do is pass through a recipe's id along with this link:

```
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create', :recipe_id => recipe.id}, {:method => :post } %>
```

Or you could make this much shorter by using a routing helper:

```
<%= link_to "Add to favorites",  add_to_favorites_path(:recipe_id => recipe), {:method => :post } %>
```

Defining that routing helper inside your `config/routes.rb` like this:

```
post '/favorites' => "favorites#create", :as => "add_to_favorites"
```

Then just find the recipe with `params[:recipe_id]` inside the controller and do what you need to do with it.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing that out, now i get undefined local variable or method `recipe' though when trying to view my_recipes page, i went with option 1

Comment: Wow,just realised you are THE Ryan Bigg who co wrote rails 3 in action, that book is next on my purchase list :)

Comment: apologies, seems as if my question wasnt spot on, issue resolved now